# C# Email with Button_Click Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm trying to create a Button_Click event that sends an email to a gmail account.  This is the error I'm getting:

Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

It's pointing out Line 63 which is:

```
client.Send(mail);
```

Here is the code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 465;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("yourclassroomconnection@gmail.com"));
    mail.From = new MailAddress("yourclassroomconnection@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "New Order";
    string bodyTemplate = Label2.Text;
    mail.Body = bodyTemplate;
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Did you try port 587?

Comment: No, but I will.  I didn't know where to start problem solving

Comment: Ok I tried that and got this error:  The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. e46sm13555277qtc.27 - gsmtp

Comment: with port 587 try this.
Enable two-factor authentication and then generate an application-specific password. Use that newly generated password to authenticate via SMTP.

Comment: Can you help me with that one?  You kinda lost me.....I'm pretty new to this

Comment: I also tried port 25 and got this error:  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 209.85.232.109:25

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code as a small test. Try sending email with minimal option. Then add other options like html support. So you can narrow down the problem when you're experimenting a new thing.

```
       try {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("your_email_address@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to_address");
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

You need to generate **app specific password** and use it here instead of your gmail password.

Please read this tutorial also.
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm

Comment: What/how does this actually help? What is `MessageBox` in `Asp.net`? Actually only the link you provided may help, as a comment.

Comment: I'm checking out the link.

Comment: That link uses MessageBox too

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding the username and password (i.e. the credentials) may be sometimes frustrating. 
What you can do is, you can add these credentials in **web.config** file only **once**. And you are good to go. Here is the better solution.

**web.config** file code goes as follows:

```
<configuration> 
  <appSettings>
   <add key="receiverEmail" value ="ReceiverEmailAddressHere"/>
  </appSettings>
  </appSettings> 
  <system.net>
  <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="yourclassroomconnection@gmail.com"> 
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" 
    userName="YourActualUsername" password="YourActualPassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

**Please note that you have to change the host according to your gmail account. I am not sure whether the host is correct.** I am using outlook to send emails so the host would be **smtp-mail.outlook.com**

This is how your web.config file would have all the necessary connection credentials that you define at one place at a time. You don't have to use it everytime you use the Email functionality in your application.

```
 protected void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
 // get the receiver email address from web.config
 msg.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverEmail"]);


 // get sender email address path from web.config file
 var address = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
 string emailAddress = address.Network.UserName;
 string password = address.Network.Password;
 NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(emailAddress, password);
 msg.Subject = " Subject text here "
}
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  client.EnableSsl = true;  
  client.Send(msg);   // send the message
```

The key point here is to access the sender's email address and receiver's email address. Note that I have used **(SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");** This will navigate your web.config file and search through the hierarchy available in it - Grabs the email address, fails if it doesn't get email address.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!